# Alphabetical case insensitive grouping of results

Tags: 8, views

My question is about grouping results alphabetically in a case insensitive way in Drupal 8. I have a view displaying people's names alphabetically grouped by last name. My problem is the following: I have some people with last name that starts with upper case D and other whose last name starts with lower case d (Example: de XXX). Right now the upper case D and the lower case d are grouped separately. I need to be able to group them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To group all of your results by Last initial, capitalized:

First, under *Format > Settings > Grouping field X*, make sure you check the box to "Use rendered output to group rows".

Second, update the field settings for the field you're using to group the results - under *Rewrite Results*, check "Trim this field to a maximum number of characters," and enter 1 for the length.

Finally, again under *Rewrite Results*, check the box to "Override the output of this field with custom text". You can use twig in the custom text field and leverage [twig's upper filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/upper.html) to convert the entire string to uppercase. You'll have to check the *Replacement Patterns* for the correct field name to use in your case, but the end result should look something like:

```
{{ field_last_name|upper }}
```

The result is your view results grouped by last initial, capitalized (whether they actually start with a capital letter or not).

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @katrin - no problem - please feel free to accept the answer if you feel it resolves your question.